# Validate the content from one environment to other environment using any automation approach

Tags: selenium, automation

I am trying to automate the process of validating the content of the pages in one environment with other environment which is having different DOM structure .

I have used **selenium web-driver** to capture the text using `getText` method and after capturing I am comparing the same, but this is failing in some places where the position of element is changed or the element is divided in to multiple tags.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need different Page Objects for each environment if the DOM's are not the same, or if the DOM elements have the same ID's, classes etc. but are just in different positions you need to use better selectors.